# Difference between char* and strncpy values in the argument

Tags: c++

I've got function, that saves values that takes in the argument. And I have to implement two ways, to accept the input - as a `char*` and then via `strncpy`.

Ie:  `a . Add("123456/7890", "John", "Doe", "2000-01-01", "Main street", "Seattle");`

It works allright, untill I use strncpy:

```
bool status;
char lID[12], lDate[12], lName[50], lSurname[50], lStreet[50], lCity[50];  

strncpy(lID, "123456/7890", sizeof ( lID));
strncpy(lName, "John", sizeof ( lName));
strncpy(lSurname, "Doe", sizeof ( lSurname));
strncpy(lDate, "2000-01-01", sizeof ( lDate));
strncpy(lStreet, "Main street", sizeof ( lStreet));
strncpy(lCity, "Seattle", sizeof ( lCity));
status = c . Add(lID, lName, lSurname, lDate, lStreet, lCity);
//is true 

strncpy(lID, "987654/3210", sizeof ( lID));
strncpy(lName, "Freddy", sizeof ( lName));
strncpy(lSurname, "Kruger", sizeof ( lSurname));
strncpy(lDate, "2001-02-03", sizeof ( lDate));
strncpy(lStreet, "Elm street", sizeof ( lStreet));
strncpy(lCity, "Sacramento", sizeof ( lCity));
// notice, that I don't even save it at this point

strncpy(lID, "123456/7890", sizeof ( lID));
strncpy(lDate, "2002-12-05", sizeof ( lDate));
strncpy(lStreet, "Sunset boulevard", sizeof ( lStreet));
strncpy(lCity, "Los Angeles", sizeof ( lCity));
status = c . Resettle(lID, lDate, lStreet, lCity);

status = c . Print(cout, "123456/7890");
//is true
```

At this point I want to print out values for ID 123456/7890... so Name:John, Surname:Doe etc.
Neverthless It prints out values, that were saved as the last ones:

```
123456/7890 Freddy Kruger
2002-12-05 Sunset boulevard Los Angeles
2002-12-05 Sunset boulevard Los Angeles
```

My `Add` is declared as:

```
  bool Add(const char * id,
        const char * name,
        const char * surname,
        const char * date,
        const char * street,
        const char * city);
```

`Resettle` function is delared similar to `Add`, it just doesn't take name and surname arguments.
All values are saved to `char **` arrays.

Could you please advice me, how to handle this situation, to be able to accept properly both inputs?

Ps: for `char*` input whole program works allright, so I don't expect any bug there..
Pps: pls don't advice me to use strings or any other constructions I don't use here - I'm very limited on imports, thus I use char* and other stuff...

Comment: You've not shown the definitions of variables such as `lID`, so it is not possible to say what's going wrong.  If they are `char lID[XX];`, you have one set of issues to worry about (notably, `strncpy()` does not guarantee null termination), and if they are `char *lID;` you have a couple of other problems to worry about.  Since you're working in C++, you shouldn't really be using `strncpy()` or arrays of `char` — you should be using `<string>` and `std::string`.

Comment: post updated....eeeh :-/ As I've said - I can't use string

Comment: Why can't you use the correct types?  When you learn a language, you should be being taught the best practices in the language.

Comment: Well...I really don't know...Those are classes for practicing algorithmization so I expect, that they want us to understand well pointers with this homework...I don't have any better explanation ~_~

Comment: Your title says `strcpy`, but your question says `strncpy`. [Beware of `strncpy`](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: @KeithThompson: and if `strncpy()` is bad, it is as nothing by comparison with `strncat()`...  _'The strncat function appends not more than `n` characters (a null character and
characters that follow it are not appended) from the array pointed to by `s2` to the end of
the string pointed to by `s1`.'_  So you have to know how many characters are already in the target string so you can deduce how many it is safe to add, which the number specified as the length in `strncat()`. If you know where the end is, why not specify where to start the copying, instead of wasting time scanning over them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `strncat` isn't *nearly* as bad as `strncpy`; `strncat` really is a "safer" version of `strcat`. Sure, it's inefficient (which can be mitigated by keeping track of the end of the string), but it does null-terminate the target and it doesn't append useless extra null characters. `target[0] = '\0'; strncat(target, source);` is pretty much what one might naively expect `strncpy()` to have been.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should be using sizeof here.  strncpy needs the length of the string(number of chars to be copy from destination string to source string).

sizeof is the size of the pointer (e.g sizrof(IID) = address size, om my system its 4).

I think you need strlen().  Also, this needs to be called on the source pointer, not the destination pointer.

```
strncpy(lID, "987654/3210", strlen ("987654/3210"));
```

<sub>Be sure that IID is enough long to copy string, otherwise buffer overflow can be problem</sub>

read [char * strncpy ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num );](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/),   and

> Copy characters from string
>   Copies the first num characters of source to destination. If the end of the source C string (which is signaled by a null-character) is found before num characters have been copied, destination is padded with zeros until a total of num characters have been written to it.

Thanks to @JonathanLeffler: (*The strlen() means the data won't be null-terminated. That's bad. At least copy strlen() + 1 bytes to get the null-terminator*)

**Note:** No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than num (thus, in this case, destination may not be a null terminated C string).

Also read about: [size_t strlen ( const char * str );](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/)

Comment: That's not my idea...this is the input, I have to be able to accept :-/

Comment: The `strlen()` means the data won't be null-terminated. That's bad.  At least copy `strlen() + 1` bytes to get the null-terminator.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but according to strncpy() manual it adds null itself.. I read over there on the link I posted...Am I wrong

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: `strncpy()` only adds nulls at the end when the string it is told to copy is shorter than the length it is told to copy.  When the length it is told to copy doesn't contain a null (as in the code with `strlen()`), it doesn't add a null.  With those calls, you are telling it to copy exactly as many non-null characters as there are in the strings, so it does not copy a null at the end.

Comment: @voodoogiant Added links and function details, you can rollback to your revision if  not like.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Now I got, I also read manual again, Now I understood your comment.   Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the `strncpy()` operations.  It is in the material you've not shown us:

```
c.Add()
c.Resettle()
c.Print()
```

One or more of those has problems, but since we can't yet see them, we can't help you debug them.

---

#### Demonstration of `strncpy()`

There's a discussion of the behaviour of `strncpy()` in the comments to [voodoogiant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193418/voodoogiant)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15984395/15168).  Here's a demonstration that:

```
strncpy(target, "string", strlen("string"));
```

does not null-terminate the output:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[32];

    memset(buffer, 'X', sizeof(buffer));
    printf("Before: %.*s\n", (int)sizeof(buffer), buffer);
    strncpy(buffer, "123456/7890", strlen("123456/7890"));
    printf("After:  %.*s\n", (int)sizeof(buffer), buffer);
    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
Before: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
After:  123456/7890XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

(Yes, I'm quite aware that the `memset()` does not null-terminate the buffer; it doesn't need to for this example because the printing is done carefully.)

Answer (score 0):

As we do not know the datatype of `lID` et al. and hence the `sizeof` it is difficult to comment. Besides why not use the `string` container from STL

Comment: I've updated the post...And as I wrote there - I'm limited on includes and I can't use string... It's a homework, so I must follow the instructions...but don't ask me why is that so 0_o